# General picture question about neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been trying to make a neural network that can compare two different anime characters. I added a lot of convolutions since it seemed like adding more abstraction would benefit what I'm trying to do.

```
model.add(Conv2D(512, (2,2), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (2,2), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (2,2), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (2,2), activation='relu'))
```

Is this a good idea to set them up like above? I Process the pictures as 20px by 20px in order to improve the speed.

Organizing the data is a nightmare, I use VLC place the pictures in the right folder by hand. I noticed that there are some pictures of other characters. Should I also add those? What are the general practices for organizing the pictures for a neural network?

Answer (score 0):

It greatly depends on what you are trying to achieve.

First off, separate the neural net from the data aquisition/processing task. In general, the better (clearer) the data, the better your results would be.

In image recognition, there are 2 standard datasets widely used. MNIST and Fashion-MNIST. They are relatively simple, but provide a good tool for benchmarking a model. Also, you can get some ideas on how to create your dataset and organize it.

Your model might produce some results, but is not perfect. You need at least one output layer (I assume you do classification here), and you could use some regularization. Have a look at [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/11/fashion-mnist-with-keras-and-deep-learning/) tutorial. It's keras, not tensorflow, but explains very well a simple and efficient model.